# Multiple anonymus threads being spawned while sending message to IntentService

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, intentservice, android-intentservice

I'm very new to Android Development and probably this question is so trivial that I could not find a clear explanation on how to even debug or approach the problem.

In my app, I have a ***SensorDataListener*** class, instantiated by the main activity and that keeps a reference of it, and in the ***onSensorChanged*** callback (and on few other events) starts a job in an IntentService called ***SensorDataCacheService***.
Now, while this mechanism seems to work properly, every time a message is added to the IntentService's queue, 3 to 5 threads (named Thread-1, Thread-2 and so on) are spawned, and remain idle forever, quickly filling up the memory until the app explodes.

I can see this happening in the Android Profiler inside Android Studio, but I tried everything to figure out what could be starting them: since they are spawned even if the ***onHandleIntent***'s content is completely commented, I'm pretty sure it has to be some sort of basically wrong setup I did.

Here you can see:
***SensorDataListener*** class

```
class SensorDataListener(owner: TrainingActivity) : SensorEventListener {
    private var context: TrainingActivity = owner
    private var settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context) as SharedPreferences
    private var sensorManager = context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    var isRecording = false

    companion object {
        private val TAG = "SensorDataListener"
    }

    // SensorEventListener overrides
    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {
        // No need for this at the moment
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
        if (event != null) {
            var intent = Intent(context, SensorDataCacheService::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(SENSOR_EVENT_ACCURACY.name, event.accuracy)
            intent.putExtra(SENSOR_EVENT_SENSOR_TYPE.name, event.sensor.stringType)
            intent.putExtra(SENSOR_EVENT_TIMESTAMP.name, event.timestamp)
            intent.putExtra(SENSOR_EVENT_VALUES.name, event.values)
            intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_TYPE.name, ADD_TO_CACHE)
            context.startService(intent)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

And ***SensorDataCacheService***

```
class SensorDataCacheService : IntentService("SensorDataCacheService") {
    private lateinit var db: CouchdbClient

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SensorDataCacheService"
        private var cache = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<FeatureData>>()
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        db = CouchdbClient(this)
    }

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        when (intent?.extras?.get(MESSAGE_TYPE.name)) {
            ADD_TO_CACHE -> {
                cache(intent)
                Log.i(TAG, "Add to cache, on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
            }
            CLEAR_CACHE -> {
                clearCache()
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Interesting is that even if I'm sure the content of the ***onHandleIntent*** method is actually performed by the IntentService's worker thread (I'm printing the thread's name from inside it), the cache seemed to be different for each call so I had to make it static (companion object in kotlin) to keep it shared among all the calls.

The only thing that is shown in the logcat (verbose level) after the crash is the following:

```
08-30 20:21:14.587 31786-9669/com.mvettosi.touchlogger A/osi.touchlogge: thread.cc:3888] Unable to create protected region in stack for implicit overflow check. Reason: Out of memory size:  4096
08-30 20:21:15.747 31786-9669/com.mvettosi.touchlogger A/osi.touchlogge: runtime.cc:558] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:558] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
    runtime.cc:558] All threads:
    runtime.cc:558] DALVIK THREADS (7053):
    runtime.cc:558] "osi.touchlogger" prio=10 (not attached)
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=9669 nice=-10 cgrp=default
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=R schedstat=( 771357331 2945888 18 ) utm=72 stm=3 core=7 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 00000000003c7324  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+220)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 00000000004a86c4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::DumpUnattachedThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+340)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 00000000004a7c6c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+460)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 000000000046a9d0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+392)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 0000000000008d2c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+724)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 00000000004905b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::ProtectStack(bool)+400)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #06 pc 00000000004901cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::InstallImplicitProtection()+132)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #07 pc 0000000000491bd8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::InitStackHwm()+504)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #08 pc 000000000048fe40  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::Init(art::ThreadList*, art::JavaVMExt*, art::JNIEnvExt*)+184)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #09 pc 000000000048f400  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+112)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #10 pc 0000000000083114  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #11 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] (Aborting thread was not attached to runtime!)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 00000000003c7324  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+220)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 000000000046a980  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+312)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 0000000000008d2c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+724)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 00000000004905b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::ProtectStack(bool)+400)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 00000000004901cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::InstallImplicitProtection()+132)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 0000000000491bd8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::InitStackHwm()+504)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #06 pc 000000000048fe40  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::Init(art::ThreadList*, art::JavaVMExt*, art::JNIEnvExt*)+184)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #07 pc 000000000048f400  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+112)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #08 pc 0000000000083114  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #09 pc 00000000000233bc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
    runtime.cc:558] 
08-30 20:21:15.754 31786-9669/com.mvettosi.touchlogger A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 9669 (osi.touchlogger), pid 31786 (osi.touchlogger)
```

Do any of you have any idea on why this is happening, or what approach could I follow to figure out what's going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "the cache seemed to be different for each call" - of course it is, service handles intents fast enough to destroy itself before next call. Try logging `onCreate` and `onDestroy` of IntenService, maybe it will lead you to your memory leak.

Comment: Hi, thanks for for the clarification. Exactly what should I log in those two methods?
I'm actually not even that sure that the problem are those threads, the Android Profile might be showing them even if they are not using up memory anymore (just noticed that closing and reopening the profiler during debugging makes them go away).
I also add the logcat of the crash.

Comment: You need to use memory profiler and see what type of objects are allocated... But if you crash that fast you're probably leaking entire `Context` objects. From your sample only static field is cache - is `FeatureData` holding any hard reference to the context?

Comment: Ty again for your reply. The FeatureData is only a bean containing basic types (int, long, float array). Interesting enough, when monitoring the memory with the Android Profiler I can't reproduce the crash: since the interaction with the UI is severely slowed because of the monitoring activity, I suspect the problem is that something is being GCed, but not fast enough.
I tried the last few hours to figure out what's going on with the ram but I cannot spot any consistent accumulation of memory... There is no particularly big or numerous object not being collected. I really don't know what todo